# Integrating Java Applet in Grails

Tags: java, grails, applet

So i have a working Grails application and as a part of it there is this Java applet. Currently these two parts live in two subversion directories (i.e. currently in the same repo, but two different top-level directories) and the applet is manually built and signed (this is an ant build). The resulting JAR File is then, again manually, copied to the apropriate directory in the grails source tree. This is then correctly included during the builing of the grails WAR file.

So far, things work, but i would like to consolidate the sources and maybe even integrate the two build processes.

Thinking about this here is my proposed course of action:

1. Include applet source in grails project structure (I dont want the sources getting pulled into the war file)
2. Construct a Build to compile, package, sign and move the applet to the target before the grails application is built in our CI environment. This can be done with multiple stage build in bamboo, somehow i guess..

So my question is: where do i put things (like DB scripts, documentation or this applet) in the grails souce tree that i dont want to be included in the war file being built? I know i can manipulate / confgure the staging phase, but is there some default way to do this?